# sparkjava android file .jks not found

Tags: android, spark-java

https://sparkjava.com

I get theses errors :

```
 starting Server@7f5f0d9[provider=null,keyStore=file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/fr.jm.garageusers/files/keystore.jks,trustStore=null]
 11:03:26.173  W  FAILED Server@7f5f0d9[provider=null,keyStore=file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/fr.jm.garageusers/files/keystore.jks,trustStore=null]: java.security.KeyStoreException: JKS not found: java.security.KeyStoreException: JKS not found
                at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:890)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:46)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:1203)
```

My call:

```
secure("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/fr.jm.garageusers/files/keystore.jks", KEYSTORE_PASSWORD,null,null);
```

Have you an idea why it doesn't found the KeyStore file .jks?
The file is present on the path.

Thank you.